# I am getting crash on "getActivity().getPackageName() " while enabling proguard but working fine without enabling

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get version name of my app in play store using jsoup with package name. when in generate build apk by enabling prograud. It throws error while getting package name.

**I am using this code to retrieve version name from play store.**

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    String newVersion = null;
    try {
        Log.e("newVersion","newVersion");

        newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "&hl=it")
                .timeout(30000)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get()
                .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]")
                .first()
                .ownText();

        Log.e("Jsoup.connect","Jsoup.connect");

        return newVersion;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return newVersion;
    }
}
```

**and my error is :**

> ```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 Process: com.iroid.android.gk4success_staffnurse, PID: 14673
> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
>     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
> Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>     at org.a.b.i.a(Unknown Source)
>     at org.a.b.i$b.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
>     at org.a.b.f$a.<init>(Unknown Source)
>     at org.a.b.f.<init>(Unknown Source)
>     at org.a.c.l.b(Unknown Source)
>     at org.a.c.l.a(Unknown Source)
>     at org.a.c.b.a(Unknown Source)
>     at org.a.c.f.a(Unknown Source)
>     at org.a.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
>     at org.a.a.b$c.e(Unknown Source)
>     at org.a.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
>     at com.iroid.android.gk4success_staffnurse.f.a$9.a(Unknown Source)
>     at com.iroid.android.gk4success_staffnurse.f.a$9.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
>     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762) 
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.io.Reader.read(char[])' on a null object reference
>     at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:435)
>     at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:354)
>     at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:342)
>     at org.a.b.i.d(Unknown Source)
>     at org.a.b.i.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
>     at org.a.b.i.a(Unknown Source) 
>     at org.a.b.i$b.<clinit>(Unknown Source) 
>     at org.a.b.f$a.<init>(Unknown Source) 
>     at org.a.b.f.<init>(Unknown Source) 
>     at org.a.c.l.b(Unknown Source) 
>     at org.a.c.l.a(Unknown Source) 
>     at org.a.c.b.a(Unknown Source) 
>     at org.a.c.f.a(Unknown Source) 
>     at org.a.a.a.a(Unknown Source) 
>     at org.a.a.b$c.e(Unknown Source) 
>     at org.a.a.b.a(Unknown Source) 
>     at com.iroid.android.gk4success_staffnurse.f.a$9.a(Unknown Source) 
>     at com.iroid.android.gk4success_staffnurse.f.a$9.doInBackground(Unknown Source) 
>     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304) 
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
> ```

Can anyone please tell how to solve this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be `Jsoup` error related to `Proguard`.

In your `proguard` file, try adding

```
-keeppackagenames org.jsoup.nodes
```

**OR**

```
-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
public *;
}
```

Comment: sorry friend I tried to upvote but i have only less reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your newVersion variable as empty string.

```
String newVersion = "";
```